# How to get folders name in excel?

Tags: excel, windows, directory

I tried in Excel using **macro** but I unable to get my exact requirement.

**Eg:**  category is the folder name. Inside this Category I have many folders like
**AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE**

How to get this **AAA to EEE** in excel.

Comment: You can use Dir() for this.

Comment: What happens if you have skipped folders -- e.g. `AAA`, `BBB`, `DDD`, `EEE`?

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the name of every folder inside the path defined in cell A1 (e.g. C:) and put them in column B:

```
Sub GetChildFolders()
  Dim fso, categoryFolder, subFolder As Object
  Dim i As Integer
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set categoryFolder = fso.GetFolder(Cells(1, 1).Value)
  i = 1
  For Each subFolder In categoryFolder.subfolders
    Cells(i, 2) = subFolder.Name
    i = i + 1
  Next subFolder
End Sub
```

Alterantively, you can create a new formula that returns a comma separated list with the folders:
(To create a new formula, add a new **module** from **insert** menu in the VBA's window)

```
Function GetChildFoldersList(ByVal path As String)
  Dim fso, categoryFolder, subFolder As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set categoryFolder = fso.GetFolder(path)
  For Each subFolder In categoryFolder.subfolders
    GetChildFoldersList = GetChildFoldersList + subFolder.Name + ", "
  Next subFolder
  If GetChildFoldersList > 0 Then
    GetChildFoldersList = Left(GetChildFoldersList, Len(GetChildFoldersList) - 2)
  Else
    GetChildFoldersList = "Folder is Empty!"
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (**Tools -> References...**), and then write `Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject`.

Comment: Note that `fso` and `categoryFolder` are typed as `Variant`. In order for them to be typed as `Object`, you have to repeat `As Object` for each variable: `Dim fso As Object, categoryFolder As Object, subFolder As Object`.

Answer (score 0):

This handles the range properly.

It doesn't presume that SubFolders returns folders in alphabetical order. (There is no mention of such a thing in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251693.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

```
'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (Tools -> References...)
Function ChildFolders(path As String) As String
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fldr As Scripting.Folder
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(path)
    Dim minFolder As String, maxFolder As String
    minFolder = ""
    maxFolder = ""
    Dim x As folder
    For Each x In fldr.SubFolders
        If x.Name < minFolder Or minFolder = "" Then
            minFolder = x.Name
        ElseIf x.Name > maxFolder Then
            maxFolder = x.Name
        End If
    Next

    Select Case True
    Case minFolder = "" And maxFolder = ""
        ChildFolders = "(No folders)"
    Case maxFolder = ""
        ChildFolders = minFolder
    Case Else
        ChildFolders = minFolder & " to " & maxFolder
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Paste this in your module to get the folders listed by name that are, in this case, on the desktop. - Have Fun

```
Sub ShowFolderList()
Dim fs, f, f1, sf
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFolder("C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\")
Set sf = f.Subfolders

r = 1
For Each f1 In sf
    
    Cells(r, 1) = f1.Name
    Cells(r, 1).WrapText = False
    r = r + 1
    
Next

End Sub
```

!! Note: turn on Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library. !!